# Block an user-agent in Nginx except those coming from a specific IP

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to figure out the best way to block an user-agent in Nginx except those comming from a specific IP. I have a solution that seems to work, but I would like to know if there is a better solution. This is my solution for now, using `if` conditions and variables:

```
if ($remote_addr != XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) {
        set $test A;
}

if ($http_user_agent ~* (python-requests)) {
        set $test "${test}B";
}

if ($test = AB) {
        return 444;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you need security consider using some real authentication (I recommend client certificates for inter-server communications) instead of IP-based auth. And in any case, the user-agent is trivial to spoof, IMO don't even bother checking it.